# Kendo UI: Incorrect tool tip show if grid cell contains " (quotes)

Tags: asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Kendo grid breaks tool-tip if " is present in the cell data

e.g. Data = asdasd"asdasd 
Tool-tip = asdasd

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **`&#34;`** instead of quote sign.

Here is [demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/UmOnU) - check Los Angeles on the left.

Check also [this link to see other codes](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)